# How to filter array on the basis of user input in angularJs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an input and a table:-

```
<label>Label1:</label>
   <input type="text" ng-model="a.value" ng-change ="filterArray(a.value)"/>

<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
      <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Branch Code</th>
            </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
            <tr ng-repeat="row in arr track by $index">
                <td>{{row}}</td>
            </tr>
      </tbody>
 </table>
```

I have an array:- a. arr = [11, 1001, 4300, AA61, 1234, B675]

What I want is when user input 1 then a.arr becomes [11, 1001, AA61, 1234] and it shows in table.

How to achieve this?

Comment: You can use ng-if to check if your variable {{row}} contains the input

Comment: You can also see this link for filters https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter

Comment: did the answer help you?

Comment: @Sajeetharan, yes thanks

Comment: @shreyagupta please mark as answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You do not need **`ng-change`** here, you can directly use **`filter`**,

**DEMO**

```js
var app = angular.module('testApp',[]);
app.controller('testCtrl',function($scope){
   $scope.arr = ['11', '1001', '4300', 'AA61', '1234','B675'];
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<body ng-app="testApp" ng-controller="testCtrl">
<label>Label1:</label>
   <input type="text" ng-model="value" />

<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
      <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Branch Code</th>
            </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
            <tr ng-repeat="row in arr  | filter:value">
                <td>{{row}}</td>
            </tr>
      </tbody>
 </table>
 </body>
```